# floating element inside a list

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

i have a list of items (loading dynamically with ajax call).

on mobile, i want to add a button (green element in the image) to the bottom of the page which is not the problem.

on desktop i want this green button to float to the right of the page, next to the items list.

i tried `float: right` to the button but then list elements are not showing under the button.

how can i do it (using bootstrap 3)?

[image]

Comment: It's all about placement. If you want your button to appear in that position for desktop, then it really needs to be the 3rd child to appear in your list items.When you get to mobile resolutions, either recall it as the last child, or call another it again, and hide the first instance, or position it `absolute` and provide enough `padding-bottom` on your `ul` to have it remain visible. Location, location, location.

Comment: where's your code?

Comment: This you can do easily using `flexbox`, post the code you have so far and I will help make it work

Answer (score 0):

add `clear: left;` (or `clear: both;`) to the button - this keeps it below the other elements.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.box{
border: 1px solid blue;
height: 50px;
float: left;
  order: 0;
margin: 0 5px 5px 0;
width: 100px;
}
.red{
  border: 1px solid red;
  float: right;
}
@media (max-width: 500px){
  
  .wrap{
display: flex;
flex-wrap: wrap;
  }
  .box{
width: 100%;
  }
  .red{
order: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="box red">1</div>
  <div class="box">2</div>
  <div class="box">3</div>
  <div class="box">4</div>
  <div class="box">5</div>
  <div class="box">6</div>
  <div class="box">7</div>
  <div class="box">8</div>
  <div class="box">9</div>
  <div class="box">10</div>
  <div class="box">11</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind using javascript to turn the last `li` into a button (rather than using a `button` element), you can achieve exactly what you want using the CSS flexbox module.

Once you have declared `display:flex` on the `ul` you can specify the `order` hierarchy of the various `li`, allowing you to re-position `li.button` (which is the final `li` in the markup) as the third `li`.

```css
.container {
padding: 6px;
border:3px solid rgb(116,150,255);
max-width: 408px;
}

ul {
display: flex;
flex-wrap: wrap;
justify-content: space-around;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
list-style-type: none;
}

li {
flex: 1 0 120px;
height: 40px;
margin: 6px;
padding-top: 20px;
color: rgb(0,74,166);
background-color: rgb(116,150,255);
line-height: 20px;
text-align: center;
font-weight: bold;
}

li:nth-of-type(n+3) {
order: 2;
flex: 1 0 90px;
}

li:nth-of-type(n).button {
order: 1;
}

.button {
color: rgb(0,166,74);
background-color: rgb(0,253,66);
}

.container, li {
box-shadow: 3px 3px 6px rgb(0,0,0);
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) { /* Example Media Query */

.container {
margin: 0 auto;
width: 300px;
}

li:nth-of-type(n) {
flex: 1 0 288px;
order: 0;
}

}
```

```html
<h2>Open this example to full page and<br />increase / decrease viewport width</h2>

<div class="container">
<ul>
<li>Item on List</li>
<li>Item on List</li>
<li>Item on List</li>
<li>Item on List</li>
<li>Item on List</li>
<li>Item on List</li>
<li class="button">Button</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

**N.B.** As stated in the snippet above the `@media` query is only an example so you can see the CSS in action. If you want a device-width-based `@media` query, you'll need something more like:

```
@media only screen and (min-device-width:320px) and (max-device-width:480px),
only screen and (min-device-width:320px) and (max-device-width:568px),
only screen and (min-device-width:360px) and (max-device-width:598px) {
```